# How to implement pay rent system with Joda money and time

Tags: time, jodatime, payment, currency, period

```
@Override
public org.joda.money.Money computeCharge(org.joda.time.DateTime from,
                                      org.joda.time.DateTime to){
```

}

Description copied from interface: Parkable

Compute the cost of parking in this lot between these times.
Specified by:computeCharge in interface Parkable
Parameters:from - The time the Vehicle is admitted.
to - The time the vehicle is released.
Returns:The cost of parking here.

For example, we charge 8 dollars per hour.

```
private void updateCharge() {
    jtc.setText(jcb.getSelectedItem() + " for " + jtf.getText());

    DateTime from = new DateTime(arriveTime.getDate());
    DateTime to = new DateTime(departTime.getDate());
    Period p = new Period(from, to);

    Parkable pk = (Parkable) jcb.getSelectedItem();
    pk.computeCharge(from, to);
    jtc.setText(pk.computeCharge(from, to).toString());
    System.out.println(jcb.getSelectedItem() + " for " + jtf.getText()
            + " costs " + pk.computeCharge(from, to));
}
```

The second coding is my calculator panel. So, the interface instance pk implements computeCharge method. Then, System.out.println(... "costs" + pk.computeCharge(from,to)). Please help me.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime to = new DateTime().minusHours(3).minusSeconds(30);
    DateTime from = new DateTime();
    System.out.println("Total Amount is = " + computeCharge(from, to));
}

public static Money computeCharge(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    int hourlyAmount = 8;
    Money result = Money.of(CurrencyUnit.USD, hourlyAmount);
    Minutes minutes = Minutes.minutesBetween(to, from);
    return result.multipliedBy(minutes.getMinutes() / 60);
}
```

You can modify this for your case.

And the output is;

```
Total Amount is = USD 24.00
```